# Folder is not deleting. How to delete this folder?

Tags: windows

See image here ->

[image: 1]

I am trying to delete "Games" folder. Folder size is huge. But it's not deleting. Even not showing a message.

If I try to delete using cmd. But it shows another error:

See image here ->

[image: 2]

What should I do now?

Comment: You should consider asking the same question on superuser.com instead. This question is off-topic here.

Comment: Did you use windows scandisk to check your disk for errors?

Comment: Oh... sorry. I'm asking there. @juhist

Comment: Check your disk. you might have bad sectors. Also check for viruses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used " chkdsk D: /f " this command and it made that folder removable.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a folder or anything from within the command prompt you have to use the word "del than the folder or file name" and not rm that is a unix command. Since your in Windows you could just right click on the folder in the file explorer and click on delete from the context menu.

Comment: As far as I know del is used for deleting file and rmdir is for deleting folder.